# How can i Override Custom button with Save & Add products(Opportunity)?

Tags: opportunity, button-overrides, save-and-new

Is it possible to Override the Standard button (Save & Add Products) on creating of Opportunity with Custom Button (Actually the thing is i want only save the record with out prompting user to select and Product) ?

but in my organization we have two kind of Users one who follow the different flow and one who follow the Standard flow...

That's why i need another button because i don't want to touch the existing functionality

Please help me if anybody have Solution of this issue

**Note :** I know salesforce have some functionality to do this from Opportunity > Opportunity setting > Uncheck the checkBox > Save.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can't just override the buttons, no. There are several other things you can do, each of which involving Visualforce, so you'll have to re-think your strategy.

Comment: You mean to say in salesforce this functinality is still not available ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In fact, there's an entire *class* of ideas where people want to do something magical in some sort of standard button. See [these ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch?keywords=override%20save) for an example. It's not likely we'll get what we want anytime soon.

Comment: there's a (probably unsatisfactory) user workaround here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003656&language=en_US (see #3)